# How to reset scene (stage1) when selecting it from Level stagemain menu

Tags: unity, c#, scene, scenemanager

Good day I have a problem when the player finish stage 1 the screen look like this [image]

Then going back to selecting level[image]

When I try to play the stage 1 again. I want to reset the stage 1 so i can play it again.
I only use 
Scene.LoadScene("stage1") in main menu to go to stage1 and
Scene.LoadScene("mainmenu") to back to main menu

[image]

Comment: Unity doesn't cache and reload runtime changes to the scene state when loading a scene a second time. So if it's loading in a different state, it's because one of your own scripts is saving information you want it to discard. To be able to help you fix that, we'd need to see that script.

Answer (score -1):

Just reload your scene when level is complete.

Comment: How would they do that? (Please `edit` the post. )

Comment: Write this line when you want to load current scene.
"SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);"

Comment: Please `edit` the post.

Comment: can you explain me little bit more. i want to know did you save your data in GameManger.cs or in *.assets file.
if you done this you need to make reset function of those value which you set on game start at the first time. and then you just need to call this function on OnEnable . Hope this will help you

Comment: Comments are transient and can be removed at any time; also, users don't look for answer there, they read the post. _Please `edit` the post._